# Query either outputs too much data, or is only in one column

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to output the SESSIONID, BUILDINGWING, SPEAKERNAME, ROOMCAPACITY, SESSIONSDATE for all sessions on the 6th of june and 13th of may. i have attempted these 2 querys:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SESSIONID, BUILDINGWING, SPEAKERNAME, ROOMCAPACITY, SESSIONDATE
FROM CONFERENCESESSION, BUILDING, ROOM, SPEAKER
WHERE ROOM.BUILDINGNO = CONFERENCESESSION.BUILDINGNO
AND ROOM.ROOMNO = CONFERENCESESSION.ROOMNO
AND CONFERENCESESSION.SPEAKERID = SPEAKER.SPEAKERID
AND SESSIONDATE LIKE '06/JUN/%'
OR SESSIONDATE LIKE '13/MAY/%'
ORDER BY SESSIONID ASC;
```

This one outputs ~700 rows, which is incorrect

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SESSIONDATE)
FROM CONFERENCESESSION
WHERE SESSIONDATE LIKE '06/JUN/%'
OR SESSIONDATE LIKE '13/MAY/%'
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(ROOMCAPACITY)
FROM ROOM
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(BUILDINGWING)
FROM BUILDING
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(SPEAKERNAME)
FROM SPEAKER
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(ROOMCAPACITY)
FROM ROOM;
```

I think this one returns the correct amount of sessions but it is all in one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not join the `BUILDING` table. This multiplies the number of records by the number of buildings because a [CROSS JOIN](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) is performed! Either join it or drop it!

```
SELECT C.SESSIONID, B.BUILDINGWING, S.SPEAKERNAME, R.ROOMCAPACITY, C.SESSIONDATE
FROM
    CONFERENCESESSION C
    LEFT JOIN ROOM R
        ON C.BUILDINGNO = R.BUILDINGNO AND
           C.ROOMNO = R.ROOMNO
    LEFT JOIN BUILDING B
        ON C.BUILDINGNO = B.BUILDINGNO
    LEFT JOIN SPEAKER S
        ON C.SPEAKERID = S.SPEAKERID
WHERE
    C.SESSIONDATE LIKE '06/JUN/%' OR C.SESSIONDATE LIKE '13/MAY/%'
ORDER BY
    C.SESSIONID ASC;
```

Also use the [modern JOIN-syntax](https://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/ansi_joins.html). It is easier to differentiate between joins and actual conditions and the mistake of forgetting a join cannot happen anymore.

If the query is correct and the data consistent, no DISTICT-clause will be needed.

Use aliases. It makes the query more compact and readable.

You seem to have the dates in text columns or at least you are treating dates using string semantics. Dates should be in DATE columns and processed with date functions or comparison operators acting on date types! It should not be necessary to do string manipulations to analyze dates.

Comment: The OP does not necessarily have dates in text columns - they could be relying on implicit conversion using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model (which has its own issues) since the filter is using string comparison semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXTRACT` to get the numeric components of the date:

```
AND ( EXTRACT( DAY FROM SESSIONDATE ) =  6 AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SESSIONDATE ) = 6 )
OR  ( EXTRACT( DAY FROM SESSIONDATE ) = 13 AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SESSIONDATE ) = 5 )
```

Also, you have no join condition for the `BUILDING` table so this is using a `CROSS JOIN`. It is much clearer  to see that if you use the new ANSI join syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       SESSIONID,
       BUILDINGWING,
       SPEAKERNAME,
       ROOMCAPACITY,
       SESSIONDATE
FROM   CONFERENCESESSION
       INNER JOIN ROOM
       ON (    ROOM.BUILDINGNO = CONFERENCESESSION.BUILDINGNO
           AND ROOM.ROOMNO     = CONFERENCESESSION.ROOMNO )
       INNER JOIN BUILDING
       ON ( ) -- You have no condition that goes here
       INNER JOIN SPEAKER
       ON ( CONFERENCESESSION.SPEAKERID = SPEAKER.SPEAKERID )
WHERE  ( EXTRACT( DAY FROM SESSIONDATE ) =  6 AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SESSIONDATE ) = 6 )
OR     ( EXTRACT( DAY FROM SESSIONDATE ) = 13 AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SESSIONDATE ) = 5 )
ORDER BY SESSIONID ASC;
```